# Blender smoke cache saved but won't load as should after Blender is closed

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, baking

Can you please advise me on how to restore cached smoke simulation in Blender? I tried this with and without checking external.

The problem is that I am calculating this for several hours to finally appear in my scene and can't effort doing this every time I start working on my project.

I wonder if the problem may be either me not starting at frame 1 with the animation and/or the smoke simulation not matching the starting frame. But the reason I did start my smoke simulation at frame -200 is that I would like the fire to be already present and visible when the rendering starts.

[image: no smoke simulation loaded]

Answer (score 1):

smoke usually has to be calculated from frame 1

If cache isn't showing try selecting the external folder again via cache menu. Have animation cursor at frame one when doing this.